# Joining multiple spark DataFrames

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, azure-databricks

I have a function which returns a DataFrame. I am running through a loop on a list(23 items) which has the function parameters, at every iteration of which I get a DataFrame. I want to join these dataframe into a single DataFrame and have the following code snippet for the same. But this transformation itself is taking a long time and any action(display, write) after that takes a long time to run as well.

```
 df_all_joined = []
    
    for table in all_tables: # all_tables have function parameters as each item
        
        df = combine_columns(*table)
        if(df_all_joined == []):
            df_all_joined = df
        else:
            df_all_joined = df_all_joined.join(df, ['join_id'],how = 'left')
    
    
# Column names are of the Dataframes being returned, and none of them match/clash.
df_all_joined = df_all_joined.select('join_id',*column_names)
```

The function is below:

```
def combine_columns(df:DataFrame,col_name:str, building_block_required:bool)->DataFrame:
    columns = df.columns
    if(building_block_required):
        df = df.withColumn(col_name, F.struct(*[F.col(i) for i in columns]))
        columns.remove("join_id")
        df = df.drop(*columns)
        if(col_name not in ['item1','item2']):
            df = df.groupby("join_id").agg(F.collect_list(F.col(col_name)).alias(col_name))
   
    return df
```

What is a better and efficient way to do the same operation?

Comment: Can you please provide an example of what your code does? And what does `combine_columns()` function do?

Comment: It seems the main reason for the slow performance was that these transformation were at the end of a long chin of transformation. When I used checkpointing with the intermediate Dataframes the execution time dropped exponentially.